How to Access and Handle Event Clicks in Vuetify's v-calendar with view-mode="week"?
I'm using Vuetify's v-calendar component with view-mode="week". I want to be able to click on the events displayed on the calendar and perform some actions, such as displaying a menu or further details about the event.
I approached the slot event, but it only worked when it was view-mode=month
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-calendar
      ref="calendar"
      class="calendar"
      v-model="value"
      :events="events"
      view-mode="week"
      :weekdays="weekday"
      @click:event="handleEventClick"
    >
      <template #event="{ event }">
        <v-card
          class="d-inline-block ma-2"
          color="light-blue"
          @click="handleEventClick({ event, nativeEvent: $event })"
        >
          <v-card-title>{{ event.title }}</v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </v-calendar>

    <v-menu
      v-model="menuVisible"
      :activator="selectedElement"
      offset-x
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>{{ selectedEvent?.title }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn text @click="menuVisible = false">Close</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const value = ref([new Date()])
const events = ref([
  { id: 1, title: 'Event 1', start: new Date(), end: new Date(), color: 'blue' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Event 2', start: new Date(), end: new Date(), color: 'red' },
])

const menuVisible = ref(false)
const selectedElement = ref(null)
const selectedEvent = ref(null)

function handleEventClick({ event, nativeEvent }) {
  console.log('Event clicked:', event.title)
  selectedEvent.value = event
  selectedElement.value = nativeEvent.target
  menuVisible.value = true
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.calendar {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
</style>


I approached the slot event, but it only worked when it was view-mode=month
I want to get the event object information by clicking on the event object created when the view-mode is a week

What's the definition of weekday?

I checked the documentation and found that this is a lab component that appears to be incomplete. The examples provided use types such as 'week', 'month', and 'day', but no differences are visible in the view. Additionally, the 'type' attribute definition is not included in the API documentation.

Thank you your comment i found this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/19020
this is bug
